# Mariadb error 1071: Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes

Tags: innodb, mariadb

A bit of context: I am trying out flowable, however tomcat chokes at a certain point while populating the database, the usual exception wall of text boils down to the title of this post. First time I put my hands on tomcat in a long time, I may be missing the obvious.

Update: this query now works.

```
CREATE TABLE flowable.FLW_EVENT_DEPLOYMENT (
ID_ VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
NAME_ VARCHAR(255) NULL,
CATEGORY_ VARCHAR(255) NULL,
DEPLOY_TIME_ datetime(3) NULL,
TENANT_ID_ VARCHAR(255) NULL,
PARENT_DEPLOYMENT_ID_ VARCHAR(255) NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_FLW_EVENT_DEPLOYMENT PRIMARY KEY (ID_)
)
```

What I did: I switched from utf8mb4 to plain old utf8 thanks to this bit ["I know UTF8mb4 can only support up to VARCHAR(191)"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/265728/utf8mb4-mariadb-10-4-max-key-length-is-767-bytes-error) (thanks @Lennart for making me think harder about this). So there is progress but I have the same error later on another query:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ACT_IDX_EVENT_DEF_UNIQ ON flowable.FLW_EVENT_DEFINITION(KEY_, VERSION_, TENANT_ID_)
```

Those three columns are respectively varchar(255) utf8_general_ci, int(11), varchar(255) utf8_general_ci.

tomcat 8.5.61

mariadb 10.4.17

I found quite a number of suggested solutions, but none seem to apply to my mariadb version, `innodb-large-prefix=ON` in particular has been deprecated, tried a few different collations without success. I have spent quite a bit of time on this already, tried to swap mariadb connector for mysql connector too to rule out a bug in the library itself.

For example I tried the accepted solution [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/231219/mariadb-10-1-38-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-767-bytes) to no avail, probably because:

- innodb_file_format is deprecated and has no effect. It may be removed in future releases.
- innodb_file_format_max surprisingly causes an error on config check, Antelope is deprecated anyway and mariadb wouldn't use it for a new table
- innodb_large_prefix was removed in 10.3.1 and restored as a deprecated and unused variable in 10.4.3 for compatibility purposes.

Comment: Have you tried accepted answer at:  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/231219/mariadb-10-1-38-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-767-bytes ?

Comment: Updated the question, thanks for the attempt!

Comment: Can you add a `create table` statement for the table (including the key) where it fails. Just the columns for the failing key will be sufficient.

Comment: Sure, it's done.

Comment: I may have mis-read your question, is it during the creation of the table or during insert you get the error? Itried your table at: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=a1d34b89e19d73321a9ad1a59864a495 and it seems to work. If it is during insert, provide the failing insert

Comment: As  much as I can be sure without digging into the code itself it is the above statement, the CREATE TABLE, that triggers the error. I would assume that given the charset and collation my mariadb is using 4 bytes per character while dbfiddle is not.

Comment: I created the table with utf8: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=c68940a22b4322414bc3f821b773db96 . You need to provide enough information to recreate the error.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @Lennart, I have made progress but the problem has shifted to a later query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ENGINE=InnoDB, not MyISAM.  Your attempts at changing settings were useless because you are not using InnoDB for the table in question.

That can be specified as the default in my.cnf *before* creating tables.  Else do it explicitly on `CREATE TABLE`.

Also, don't blindly use 255, instead use sensible limits.

Comment: You were right, most tables were created as innodb (probably because they were declared with constraints) so I missed that detail. Also, not my application, so I'd rather not mess with field length.

Comment: The engine comes from either explicitly declaring it when the table is created, or from a default in the config.  Constraints, FKs, etc are simply ignored by MyISAM.  I mentioned the 255 because it factors into the 1000 limit, and you could still hit a _different_ limit in InnoDB.  Do something like `SELECT MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(col)) FROM tbl;` to see what the longest text for `col`.  Then use `ALTER` to adjust it down to some max that is somewhere between the max and 255.  For example, hardly any kind of "name" (person, city, etc) is longer than 70.